How to know what (geo)location Firefox sends to websites
It is not a secret that Firefox can share location with websites if the permission is granted.
The question is, how to check what location is actually shared to a website? Is the value can be achieved somewhere in DevTools?

Not just Firefox, but all major browsers can do this. It may be different on a (gps enabled) mobile device than on a laptop, or desktop though

@Berend Indeed. But every browser have own way to check the coordinates. I was curious about Firefox at this time ;) However, I suppose that my solution below should work in Chrome as good as in Firefox

Have a website tell you – there exist "test this-or-that API" websites for geolocation as well as other browser APIs. One example I found is https://browserleaks.com/geo; another is the Mozilla web developer documentation site at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API/Using_the_Geolocation_API#examples which also has example code that you can host on your own server somewhere if you're concerned about privacy.

Cool! However we need just a single JavaScript line to get the data. No own server is needed. I added own solution based on your answer.

To achieve geo coordinates you have to:

Go to page asking for location (we suppose that permission to access location already granted to the resource)
Open console (Ctrl + Shift + i)
Insert and run
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {location.replace(`https://www.google.com/maps/search/${pos.coords.latitude},${pos.coords.longitude}`)})


You will be redirected to Google maps with current location

